# Binder Thread failed

Tags: android

`08-27 22:17:20.980: INFO/AndroidRuntime(299): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed`
This is LogCat information please help me.

Comment: Are you experiencing any actual failure in functionality?  If so, specifically what is broken? Android device logs unfortunately tend to be full of records of suboptimal situations that don't actually get in the way of intended functionality - which makes it harder to find any actual failures.

Comment: stringArray is not displaying on Emulator

Comment: That's entirely meaningless without context.

Comment: Please mind of the title of the question provide more information where does exception occurs and any relevant information.

Comment: I provide u link for my code. Please check it and send me useful information. Thanks for help. Link http://pastebin.com/9zCAYEQv

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain it is not related to your app.  Filter your logcat with AndroidRuntime and you will see that message right after "Shutting down VM"  and a few others that start with "AndroidRuntime START" and the grouping repeats with different pid's.  To me, it looks like some kind of system maintenance, but that is a guess.

Comment: I provide u link for my code. Please check it and send me useful information. Thanks for help. Link pastebin.com/9zCAYEQv

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your console log(which is most of the time impractical), you'll find the answer.
You didn't add the Launcher for one of your activities.
try to add this lines in your manifest file (to the activity that you want your application to start with):

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```